# backticks `cat filename` failed, file content is several commands

Tags: linux, bash, cat, backticks

My system is CentOS 6.5 
When I want to use backtick to run the commands in filename, i got the result below:

the file's content is below:

```
[liu-uil@~ 15:54:16]$cat test
echo 1;
echo 2;
echo 3;

[liu-uil@~ 15:54:18]$`cat test`
1; echo 2; echo 3;
[liu-uil@~ 15:54:24]$
```

the commands after the first echo are all treated as text plain, I don't know why? Could somebody kindly explain this to me? Thank you very much!

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Whatever your end goal is, `cat` in backticks is probably not what you should be using.

Comment: I just want to learn a little more about the backticks and  solve this problem :) (a little nerd )

Answer (score 2):

Command substitution is one of the expansions. Expansions happen when the command line was already split into commands, it's too late to create new commands.

You can use

```
eval `cat 1`
```

to call the shell parser again to split the string into commands and run them.

Comment: Aha, I got it , now I know the reason why it doesn't work, but eval 'cat test' and \`\`cat test\`\` can neither get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Only the first word in the result of a backtick command is interpreted as a command. Remaining text is the argument list.

If you want to run commands in a file, you don't need backticks, you need the [dot (.) command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_%28Unix%29):

```
[liu-uil@~ 15:54:16]$. test
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know the . test method :)